# How can I scroll to the top of my textbox after printing some text to it?

Tags: c#, textbox, scroll

I am printing a lot of text to a textbox and would like it to scroll to the top after the printing is complete.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set the `SelectionStart = 0;` for your TextBox. See here at MSDN about [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx). You can then set your `SelectionLength = 1;`

You can then call [ScrollToCaret](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

```
textbox.SelectionStart = 0;
```

that works in Wpf and in WinForms Applications

Answer (score 2):

For WinForms, use a combination of SelectionStart = 0 and ScrollToCaret()

Answer (score 1):

Just use navigation keys after making sure the control has focus:

```
SendKeys.Send("^({HOME})");
SendKeys.Send("^({END})");
```

etc. as needed

Answer (score 0):

`SelectionStart = 0` did not work for me.

I used `richTextBox1.Clear();` before loading new text.